# Cassandra - using PreparedStatement with ListenableFuture

Tags: java, cassandra

Im attempting to make async writes to a Cassandra cluster using **ListenableFuture** as follows:

```
private static Cluster cluster = null;
private ListeningExecutorService executorService;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
private Session session = null;

... 

executorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE));
...

public void writeValue(Tuple tuple) {
    ListenableFuture<String> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
       @Override
       public String call() throws Exception {
           if(session == null) {
               session = getCluster().connect("dbname");
               preparedStatement = session.prepare(queryString);
           }

           try {
               BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind(tuple values);
               session.execute(boundStatement);
           } catch(Exception exception) {
                // handle exception
           }

           return null;
       }
    });
```

If I set **POOL_SIZE** to 1 everything works.
If I set **POOL_SIZE** to > 1 I get errors as follows:

> Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Tried to execute unknown prepared query : 0x75c5b41b9f07afa5384a69790503f963. You may have used a PreparedStatement that was created with another Cluster instance.

So I `session` and `preparedStatement` into local vars. Then I get warnings about `Re-preparing already prepared query ...` plus it's creating a new session every time.

I want to reuse as much as possible. What am I doing wrong and what are my options?

Would it help to make this class static?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have all sorts of race conditions here and execution isn't thread safe.

Each of `Cluster`, `Session`, and `PreparedStatement` are meant to be application scoped singletons, ie. you only need one (one for each query for `PreparedStatement`).

However, you are recreating a `Session` and potentially preparing `PreparedStatement` multiple times.

Don't. Initialize your `Session` once, in a constructor or some location that only runs once and prepare your statements at the same time. Then use the `Session` and `PreparedStatement` where appropriate.

---

Using a single threaded executor, everything runs as if it was synchronous. When you add more threads, many of them may call

```
session.prepare(queryString);
```

at the same time.  Or the `PreparedStatement` you use here

```
BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind(tuple values);
session.execute(boundStatement);
```

might be different from the one you initialized

```
preparedStatement = session.prepare(queryString);
```

even within the same thread of execution. Or you might be attempting to execute the `PreparedStatement` with a different `Session` than the one used to initialize it.

---

[Here are some things you should be doing when using CQL drivers.](https://ahappyknockoutmouse.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/246/)

> 1. **Is a prepared statement bound on one session or is it useable on another session?**
>
>    A prepared statement is derived from a particular session instance.
>      So when you prepare a statement and it is sent over to the server, it
>      is sent to the cluster with which this session instance is associated
>      with.

The javadoc of [`Session`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html) states

> Session instances are thread-safe and usually a single instance is
>   enough per application.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to use the driver's asynchronous API. Instead of calling `execute` (which will block your thread for the duration of the query), call `executeAsync` and register a callback on the resulting future to process the result.

If that callback is expensive and you don't want to block the driver's internal I/O thread, then you can provide your own executor:

```
ListenableFuture<ResultSet> future = session.executeAsync(statement);
Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
    public void onSuccess(ResultSet rs) { ... }
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) { ... }
  }, 
  executorService);
```

[This page](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/features/async/) in the documentation has a few tips on async programming.

Comment: Given that the `execute` statement is already inside a **ListenableFuture** - why do I need to (re)wrap it as an `executeAsync()`?

Comment: `execute` blocks until the driver receives a response to the request. Your application thread can't do anything else in the meantime. In contrast, in my example the thread is only busy during the callback's execution, not while waiting for the response to come.